# Invalid syntax on using With in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

the following code opens a file searches for a word or phrase, then opens the file in an array, it then adds two new objects after the word or phrase and then re-writes it to the file, the with statments do not work, when compiled it produces a syntax error saying the file = open(...) the '=' is not valid but it is the assignment operator. help?

```
def edit(file_name,search_parameters,added_data,second_data):

    with(file = open(file_name,'r')):
        lines = list(file)
        file.close()
    linenum = (num for (num,line) in enumerate(lines) if search_parameters in line).next()
    lines[linenum+1] = added_data
    lines[linenum+1] = second_data

    with (file2 = open(file_name,"w")):
        file2.writelines(line + '\n' for line in lines)
        file2.close()
```

Comment: In python, assignment is a statement, not an operator.  It does not return a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `as` keyword:

```
with open(file_name,'r') as file:

with open(file_name,"w") as file2:
```

Here is a reference on [Python's with statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

---

Also, these two lines are unncessary:

```
file.close()

file2.close()
```

Using a with statement to open a file will cause it to be closed automatically when the with statement's code block is exited.  In fact, that is the only reason why you use a with statement to open files.

Comment: It is also noteworthy that OP does not need to explicitly close the file. Perhaps an explanation of the `with` statement is required.

Comment: @AlexThornton - Good idea, I missed that.  Let me mention it.